# VBA passing Excel.Range as Array into a function

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and little bit confused by the two codes below. Could someone tell me what's the difference here? The first code works fine, but the second will return #VALUE! Error.

Example 1

```
Function Example1()
Dim vtSecurities As Variant
vtSecurities = Array("AAPL US Equity", "GOOG US Equity")
Example1 = vtSecurites
End Function
```

Example 2

```
Function Example2(ticker As Excel.Range)
Dim vtSecurities As Variant
vtSecurities = ticker.Value
Example2 = vtSecurites
End Function
```

So I tried and them seem to return the same array in worksheet. However, in the actual big application, the array (vtSecurities) will be passed to another function and Example2 does not work. So I guess my question is - does those Example1 and Example2 return the exact same results?

Comment: If the code posted here is exactly the same as you use in your "big application", then: fix the line > Example2 = vtSecurites to Example2 = vtSecurities. The question "Example1 and Example2 return the exact same results?" is impossible to answer since we don't know the value of the "ticker" when calling the Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As BigBen mentioned `.Value` gives you a 2D array but if you do want it to be a 1D (and it's from a singular column), then it's just a small fix:

```
Function Example2(ticker As Range)
    Dim vtSecurities As Variant, arr(), i As Long
    arr = ticker.Value
    ReDim vtSecurities(1 To UBound(arr, 1))
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        vtSecurities(i) = arr(i, 1)
    Next i
    Example2 = vtSecurities 'there was a typo here, just fyi
End Function
```

As mentioned by freeflow & BigBen: Transpose on an array in VBA the array must be no more than 65,536 (2^16) rows long, but if you are dealing with smaller ranges, it's easier to use:

```
Function Example2(ticker As Range)
    Dim vtSecurities As Variant, arr(), i As Long
    vtSecurities = Application.Transpose(ticker.Value)
    Example2 = vtSecurities
End Function
```

Comment: Or you could just use Worksheetfunction.transpose to avoid the for loop.

Comment: Though `Transpose` will fail if there are more than `2^16` rows.

Comment: That's what caused me to opt for the for-loop in most of my cases, yeah.

Comment: If you are using 2^16 rows in Excel you deserve all the issues you get.

Comment: We have 370k articles in our system, don't really have a choice every time.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what range you pass.

- If `ticker` is a single cell, e.g. `Range("A1")`, then its `.Value` is not an array.
- If `ticker` is a multicell contiguous range, e.g. `Range("A1:A2")`, then its `.Value` is a one-based 2D array.
- If `ticker` is a multicell noncontiguous range, e.g. `Range("A1:A2,C1:C2")`, then `.Value` refers to the first area only,  i.e. `A1:A2`.

In any case, the two functions return different things.

Suggested Reading: [Chip Pearson on Arrays and Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx).